# Examples for p-form gauge fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory, bosons

I don't completely understand the notion "p-form". Can you give me examples of 1-form, 2-form and 3-form gauge fields? What kind of p-form is e.g. the Higgs field, the electromagnetic four-potential, etc.?

Comment: Higgs, photons, W-Bosons are charge carriers, not gauge fields. Their description in QFT is achieved by means of gauge theories on fibre bundles, which in turn make use of tensor calculus on manifold, where $p$-form formalism takes place.

Comment: Sorry, I meant not the gauge bosons but the corresponding gauge fields such as the electromagnetic four-potential. Why do we have a 3-form for Higgs and not a 2-form?

Comment: This question (v3) seems like a list question.

Comment: There is another answer at http://www.physicsoverflow.org/33567

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether I understood the intention of your question correctly.

In electrodynamics you usually use a 1-form $A=A_{\mu}dx^{\mu}$ to write down an action 
\begin{equation*}
S = \int F \wedge \star F 
\end{equation*}
with the 2-form field strength $F=dA$, which the gives the known (vacuum) Maxwell equations.

Scalar fields $\phi$ (such as the Higgs) are described by 0-forms or alternatively by their dual $(d-2)$-forms in $d$ dimensions.

In string theory one finds cousins of the electromagnetic field $A$, but they turn out to be $p$-forms, e.g. in type IIB we have the R-R-fields $C_0, C_2,C_4$,...

psm

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, unfortunately I am not used to your notations. Your action is equivalent to $S=\int F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu}$ or not? What exactly means wedge product followed by Hodge operator? And $dA$ means $d_{\mu}A_{\nu}-d_{\nu}A_{\mu}$?

Comment: And what do you mean with "dual field", what is that physically?

Comment: Yes, up to some factor $F \wedge \star F \sim d^dx F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$. In $d$ dimensions, $\star F$ is by definition a $(d-2)$-form if $F$ is a 2-form. Then, the wedge product can be applied as in the case of wedging a p- and a q-form. And $dA= \partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}dx^{\mu}\wedge dx^{\nu}$. (See definition of exterior derivative.)

Comment: Concerning the dual field: Take a p-form potential $C_p$. Its field strength tensor is then $F=dC_p$, a $(p+1)$-form. Thus, in $d$ dimensions $\tilde{F} \equiv \star dC_p$ is a $(d-p-1)$-form, and locally there exists a $(d-p-2)$-form $\tilde{C}_{d-p-2}$ s.t. $\tilde{F}=d \tilde{C}$. We call $\tilde{C}$ the dual field to $C$. Physically they should be equivalent...

Comment: Thanks again! I am just wondering where these dual fields come from, because up to know I never met them in QFT. When the dual field is a (d-2)-form if the field is a 2-form, how can they then be physically equivalent?

Comment: You're welcome! Careful, the dual field of a 2-form is a $(d-4)$-form. One has to figure this out by dualising the field strength tensor. (See my last comment.) To see, why these should be physically equivalent: i) One can rewrite the action $S[C_p]$ into $S[\tilde{C}_{d-p-2}]$ and they're structurally identical. In particular, the Bianchi identity & the eq. of motion for $C$ become the e.o.m. & Bianchi id. for $\tilde{C}$. ii) The on-shell degrees of freedom for a $p$-form and a $(d-p-2)$-form gauge field are identical.

Comment: Notice however, that I'm not sure whether the physical equivalence holds true in all field theories involving $p$-form gauge fields. But it should be true at least for abelian gauge fields with Lagrangians involving kinetic terms as above. Maybe someone else can provide more details...

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your comments, they are very helpful! However, I think you made a mistake in your second and third comments, since the dual of a p-form should rather be a (d-p)-form instead of a (d-p-2)-form (otherwise the dual of a 2-form in 2d would be a -2-form).

Comment: No, in my conventions we have a $p$-form gauge field $C$. Indeed, $\star C$ would then be a $(d-p)$-form, but this is not (!) what we call the dual field to $C$. The definition of dual fields involves the duals of the field strength tensors (corresponding to the gauge fields), see my third post.